# How can I decrease the time for "npm install" in react js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npm-install

I have created a react application without using **"create-react-app"**.
Now when I try to install the **"node modules"** using command **"npm install"** it takes about 3 minute to install.
[image]

Is there any way by which I can decrease this installation time?

**Note:-** My **npm** version is **9.2.0** and **node** version is **v16.15.1**

Comment: use `yarn` it's faster them npm in installing project packages

Comment: Why is that a problem? Node projects are incredibly bloated, it is just how the ecosystem is set up. But it normally only takes this long during first install when everything needs to e freshly downloaded.

Comment: Get better internet or use less dependencies.

Answer (score -2):

Problem:

> NPM does not perform well if you do not keep it up to date. However,
> bleeding edge versions have been broken for me in the past.

Solution:

> As per I think use node version manager [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm), with its --lts
> flag

Install it:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash
```

Then use this often to upgrade to the latest "long-term support" version of NPM:

```
nvm install --lts
```

Note : you'll likely have to reinstall all packages when you get a new npm version.